# How do i get rid of' Tkinter.Tcl error- could not recognize data in image file'?

Tags: python, tkinter

Every time, even though I have the source file, the same error message appears - 'Tcl error...could not recognize data in image file'. The problem also occurs with other images present in my disk drive.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.geometry("420x420")
window.title('My first GUI programme')
source='D:\\Desktop\\op.jfif'
icon=PhotoImage(file=source)
window.iconphoto(True, icon)
window.mainloop()
```

Here goes the error:

```
PS D:\Documents\pythonProject> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python/python.exe" "d:/Documents/pythonProject/Learning python/Practice.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Documents\pythonProject\Learning python\Practice.py", line 6, in <module>  
    icon=PhotoImage(file=source)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "D:\Desktop\op.jfif"
```

I don't know if there is any problem with my code or i need to change any settings. I would be thankful to you if you provide me any assistance.

Comment: Python Tkinter supports GIF, PGM, PPM, and PNG. So, try changing the extension of the file to one of them

Comment: you can also try using `Image` and `ImageTk` from `pillow` library (`PIL`), also don't use `*` when importing

Comment: A JFIF file is a bitmap graphic that uses JPEG compression. Try importing PIL to view it.

Comment: @PCM: just changing the extension doesn't do anything but change the name. It's the contents of the file that need to be changed.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes you are right, i had to convert my image to a png file by changing its data through an online converter, and it, then, worked for me, thx for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this by changing the file extension and file content of my image file to 'png' which worked in python.

Answer (score 1):

Python Tkinter supports GIF, PGM, PPM, and PNG. So, try changing the extension of the file to one of them

i see your problem

i also have the same problem